# Is it possible to use method reference with static method of interface?

Tags: java, lambda, method-reference

This is my first code:

```
public class MethodReference {
    public static void main (String []args) {
        Stream<String> s = Stream.of("brown bear", "grizzly");
        s.sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder()).forEach(System.out::print);
        //...
    }
}
```

Result: grizzlybrown bear

This is my second code:

```
public class MethodReference {
    public static void main (String []args) {
        Stream<String> s = Stream.of("brown bear", "grizzly");
        s.sorted(Comparator::reverseOrder()).forEach(System.out::print);
        //...
    }
}
```

Result: compiler error

My questions: 
Why is there a compiler error in the second code?
Can't I use the method reference for static method of functional interface?

I know I can't use method reference with default method of functional interface.
I know I can use method reference with a class in 5 cases:

Class

- Class::staticMethod
- Class::instanceMethod
- instance::instanceMethod
- Class::new

Functional Interface

- Interface::abstractMethod

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Comparator::reverseOrder() - this is probably wrong in your second code snippet

Comment: `Comparator::reverseOrder()` a method reference does not have parenthesis - ever

Comment: you need to study what _method reference_ is.

Comment: `I know I can't use method reference with default method of functional interface`. This is false. You can have i.e. `Function::andThen`, where `Function` is a functional interface and `andThen` is a default method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Comparator.reverseOrder()` is an expression which resolves to the `Comparator` type, because that's what it returns.

`Comparator::reverseOrder` is an expression which resolves to **a method** which takes no arguments and returns a `Comparator` e.g. a `Supplier<Comparator<String>>`, though it could be any matching functional interface.

In the second instance you are trying to pass a method (which provides a `Comparator`) as an argument. The method doesn't want that - it just wants the `Comparator` itself.

You could think of it like this (just pseudo-code to demonstrate the point):

```
s.sorted(new Comparator())
```

vs

```
s.sorted(new Supplier(new Comparator()))
```

---

To answer your second question as to whether it's ever possible to use a method reference for a static method of an interface - yes, absolutely!

If we declare the following method:

```
<T> void giveMeAComparatorSupplier(Supplier<Comparator<T>> supplier) { }
```

then we can definitely call it with a method reference

```
giveMeAComparatorSupplier(Comparator::reverseOrder);
```

---

(And FYI your method reference syntax is wrong - it never uses `()`)

Answer (score 3):

Two things are wrong with your second code.  First, method references do not use parentheses or arguments at all.  You would need to supply only the method that would be called later; you are not calling the method at that point.

Second, the `sorted` method takes a `Comparator`, not a functional interface that would supply a `Comparator`.  The method needs a `Comparator` already created and ready to go, not a functional interface that will supply a `Comparator` when needed.

It has nothing to do with the fact that `Comparator` is an interface; one can generally create a method reference to a `static` interface method.  It has everything to do with the fact that `sorted` needs an actual `Comparator` instance and not an instance of a functional interface, which is when you could supply a method reference.

So even if you take off the parentheses, it still won't compile.  Only your first code, which directly passes a `Comparator`, will compile and work as expected.